# IMAP flags always has :Seen flag

Tags: ruby, imap

I am importing emails into an application using imap:

I have the following code:

```
since_time = Net::IMAP.format_date sync_time

google.email.all folder: folder, keys: [ 'SINCE', since_time ] do |mail, imap, uid|
  flags = imap.uid_fetch(uid, ['FLAGS'])[0].attr['FLAGS']

  if flags.include?(:Seen)
    #flags always has :Seen
```

I want to mark emails as unread if they have not been read but using the code above, the :Seen flag is always returned.

My understanding was that the :Seen flag is only returned if the email has been marked as read.

Am I misunderstanding how the flags should work?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the rest of your application triggers the `FETCH` command of some `BODY` parts. As a side effect of that operation, the `\Seen` keyword is set automatically. You are probably looking for `BODY.PEEK`. It is also a good idea to use `EXAMINE` instead of `SELECT` for opening the mailbox read-only.